# How should I write a logger proxy?

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing, python-3.8

I had a function for making a logger proxy that could be safely passed to multiprocessing workers and log back to the main logger with essentially the following code:

```
import logging
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager

class SimpleGenerator:
    def __init__(self, obj): self._obj = obj
    def __call__(self): return self._obj

def get_logger_proxy(logger):
    class LoggerManager(BaseManager): pass
    logger_generator = SimpleGenerator(logger)
    LoggerManager.register('logger', callable = logger_generator)
    logger_manager = LoggerManager()
    logger_manager.start()
    logger_proxy = logger_manager.logger()

    return logger_proxy

logger = logging.getLogger('test')

logger_proxy = get_logger_proxy(logger)
```

This worked great on python 2.7 through 3.7.  I could pass the resulting `logger_proxy` to workers and they would log information, which would then be properly sent back to the main `logger`.

However, on python 3.8.2 (and 3.8.0) I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "junk.py", line 20, in <module>
    logger_proxy = get_logger_proxy(logger)
  File "junk.py", line 13, in get_logger_proxy
    logger_manager.start()
  File "/anaconda3/envs/py3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 579, in start
    self._process.start()
  File "/anaconda3/envs/py3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/py3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/context.py", line 283, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/py3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.py", line 32, in __init__
    super().__init__(process_obj)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/py3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 19, in __init__
    self._launch(process_obj)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/py3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.py", line 47, in _launch
    reduction.dump(process_obj, fp)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/py3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'get_logger_proxy.<locals>.LoggerManager'
```

So it seems that they changed something about ForkingPickler that makes it unable to handle the closure in my `get_logger_proxy` function.

My question is, how can I fix this to work in python 3.8?  Or is there a better way to get a logger proxy that will work in python 3.8 they way this one did for previous versions?

Comment: Not certain that this is a regression, but you might want to file an issue for this on bugs.python.org

Comment: Also, https://bugs.python.org/issue34034 may be related, though it notes the change as occurring in 3.7

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Posted https://bugs.python.org/issue40942